# Does SQLAlchemy support Firebird 3 yet?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Does SQLAlchemy support Firebird 3? I ask because when using the below model, SA seems to not create the expected DDL (or metadata, not sure of the correct term) for the intended primary key id.

**Engine used**

```
firebird+fdb://username:password@...
```

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
```

I expected the following DDL to be generated:

```
create table User (
  id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
  username varchar(128) not null)
```

Actual DDL upon inspection is:

```
create table User (
  id integer not null,
  username varchar(128) not null)
```

Comment: "The Firebird dialect within SQLAlchemy is not currently supported. The dialect is not tested within continuous integration and is likely to have many issues and caveats not currently handled." https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/firebird.html

Comment: I was wondering what that means. I'm moving to postgres meanwhile :D